# How can I remove hover style in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have defined this hover for div element

```
div.MyCSSClass:hover
{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

This is my HTML source:

```
   <div class="
    <ul class="MyParentCSSClass">
    <li>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="MyCSSClass">
               <!-- I want to remove CSS hover for this div element -->
```

I want to remove the hover when the div.MyCSSClass is a child of MyParentCSSClass, So I add this to remove the hover style in CSS:

```
.MyParentCSSClass div.MyCSSClass:hover
{
}
```

But it did not work. I still see the same hover style.
Is there a way to remove hover in CSS without me creating a new CSS class for my div tag? I want to keep the same name as I have other CSS property uses the 'MyCSSClass'.

Thanks for the suggestion. I tried

```
background-color: none !important;
```

But when I look into chrome, that CSS is being over-written by

```
.MyGrandParentClass div.MyCSSClass:hover
{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

and the html source is

```
  <div class="MyGrandParent">
    <ul class="MyParentCSSClass">
    <li>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="MyCSSClass">
               <!-- I want to remove CSS hover for this div element -->
```

My question is how my 'Remove hover' css rule is being over-written? I have put "!important" to my rule.

Comment: Instead of using empty brackets, set the `background-color` to `none` or `inherit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.MyParentCSSClass div.MyCSSClass:hover { 
  background-color: none;
}
```

This will overwrite the background color given by `div.MyCSSClass:hover`. if you are keeping `MyParentCSSClass div.MyCSSClass:hover` empty as `MyParentCSSClass div.MyCSSClass:hover {}`, it will not overwrite anything or doing nothing actually.

Comment: you might consider `background-color: initial` effectively the same, semantically gets across the point that you're clearing the field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write all the previously added styles to the hover event. In the case you specified, please do the following:

```
.MyParentCSSClass div.MyCSSClass:hover
{
   background-color: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Background-color : none; is not w3c standard. It will work on some browser but according to w3c standard it's not right way.

So try to use background-color: transparent which will work good on all browsers and w3c can validate your code.
[image]

Have fun.